# Can Ugh-Zan IV be defeated at all on Serious difficulty at 400% health?

Tags: serious-sam-3-bfe

I wanted to try how the ultimate Serious Sam 3 tastes like, so I started the last level on Serious difficulty with infinite ammo and 400% enemy health, for a whopping ×57 multiplier. It's pretty serious and in the last few waves you just have to spam cannonballs (it's still more fun than your run of the mill 16 player coop where you're trying to engage some enemies that you can kill normally and people just spam cannons away for fun and profit).

Things went pretty nice (given that I was alone for pretty much 98% of the level) and I managed to survive enough to reach the final boss with over one million points (you lose 10k on death), then Ugh-Zan arrived.

Well, [my use-one-bar-then-spam-cannons strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/39941/23) didn't work so well, perhaps unsurprisingly. So I kept throwing bars at his behind. At the 5th bar, he stopped having room in his back for new bars, apparently. The boss fight loop then becomes:

1. Ugh-Zan goes for the sand whale, cannon spam to fight his regeneration is practically useless. He *will* have 100% health at the end of this phase.
2. Ugh-Zan turns around and celebrates, then five lightning bolts turn him to 20% health and regeneration stops. Cannon spam gets him to 5%, then he resumes.
3. Ugh-Zan engages you, and cannon-spam to fight his regen is again useless, because...
4. Ugh-Zan is again struck by five lightnings, but those lightning drop him at 20% health anyway, even if he had 60% to start with. They're just scripted that way. You have a little more time to strike this time around, and I got him to 1% at best. Then he resumes regenerating and I'm back to square one.

When another player joined the fight, things got *worse* as each cannonball now made *less* of a dent on the skin of this serious boss.

<sub>After a couple of cycles, he left. Then I noticed I'd died for the 40th time, and I was experiencing a very annoying glitch where I'd get sucked away from the battlefield into sand whale territory (land of the instantly overheating jet-pack), so I'd have to fall, get killed by mobs, respawn, get "instakilled" by the whale except I have respawn invulnerability, be stuck in place until I get killed again and then get respawned in the middle of the square. Cannon spam to fight his regen is pointless anyway, but being stuck like that is enraging, so I joined him in "ragequitting".</sub>

Can Ugh-Zan be defeated at all on Serious difficulty and 400% strength? How many players are required? How many bars in the back are needed?

Comment: That sounds mighty serious.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you will need at least 8 or 28 players who are expert at playing that game.

Comment: Did you ever see the answers posted by "Leptys5" on this [topic on SeriousZone](http://forums.seriouszone.com/showthread.php?t=60829)? I gather "bp_" is you :)

Comment: @nick ...uh no I hadn't! I expected getting email notifications but never got any.

Comment: If you haven't already defeated this seriously serious boss, then I hope the suggestions posted on that topic help you in doing that - that is if you still have an interest in playing the game.

Comment: When you say "spamming cannon balls" what exactly do you mean by that. Normally I would understand spamming as "repeatedly clicking the fire button in very fast succession" but with cannon balls, this will launch several slow cannon balls. If you charge the cannon it takes quite long but the cannon ball will inflict a lot more damage. So, please clarify on "spamming" in this context.

Comment: Everything is possible...
with hacks.

Comment: Wow.. this question has gone unanswered for 2 years...

Comment: After doing a two-minute search on YouTube, I [have to answer yes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZ-VHz7y3IY). The method he takes is a lot of dodging and letting the level do the work. You had the right idea with the lightning, it takes him down low enough that cannon-spam should do the trick. **Edit**: Apparently this doesn't account for the 400% heatlh requirement. My apologies.

Comment: This isn't with the 400% enemy health

Comment: Updated to match.

Comment: this can only be done if you are serious enough

Comment: @theidiotgamer99 Please do not engage in edit warring.

Comment: Is the devastator better than charged cannon balls? I don't have SS3 anymore to test...

Comment: @GlenWheeler It depends on the rate of fire; it might very well be better.

Comment: @DarkWolffe well, yes, you had it right, just do it for longer.

Answer (score 2):

## It is POSSIBLE...

Ugh-Zan IV can be defeated at 400% health. I personally decided to go out of my way, and actually buy the game and try it out for the sake of this question. I managed to beat him along with the help of 3 different expert players (names listed below) First of all, your strategies are not going to work if you try any ordinary strategy. We first decided to go along with your strategy and try to see if we could manage to beat him with a normal cannon-spam with something else, I can't quite remember. We quickly failed at this... Next, we tried to use an C-4 against him, but couldn't manage to land one, so that was a fail and a wipe.

We finally managed to do it by throwing about 7 poles into his back and after he was struck by lightning he was down to about a quarter of his max health. After that, the sand-whale came back and started wrestling him again. In this time, we managed to spam him with cannonballs. By the time, he was done wrestling the sand-whale, and the sand-whale had retreated once again, we did an all-out blitz with the poles, cannonballs, and rocket launcher. In the end, we managed to bring him down, so **YES IT IS possible**!

**Players with me: OpenUpSweety, xxX_Jack***Hunter_Xxx, and UpandDownandUp**

Comment: That's kind of amazing. Did you record a video?

Comment: Sadly, no... My computer is a bit laggy, so we couldn't manage to record a video without major lag, atleast I didn't. I can ask the other players though

Answer (score -1):

Although there is no way to prove that it's impossible there are no (reliable) sources on the internet that prove it can be done. If you want to beat it on multiplayer you should probably have at **least** 5 expert players with you although I would probably recommend having about 15 expert players to beat him.

Comment: ...I honestly think two might do

Comment: @badp depends how good you are at the game