# How to pass the Barge Death challenge?

Tags: jamestown

The second challenge of the third challenge pack is pretty serious. You must survive for 15 seconds, you're invulnerable for the first five and the next ten of those 15 seconds are entirely full of bullets.

How do you survive that?

Comment: It's only *[pretty serious](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40020/can-ugh-zan-iv-be-defeated-at-all-on-serious-difficulty-at-400-health)*? ;)

Comment: @agent86 It can't be _too_ serious if I stumbled on the trick at the second try :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to:

1. **Push all the way to the top right corner.** If you use the gunner, you can use right click quickly to align your beams downwards and try to damage some of the bullet-spamming ships, just to avoid taking chances. The right position to be, then, is where you're damaging some of the ships below you. 10 seconds left.
2. **Move swiftly to the left** while keeping as high as possible as soon as the ships start firing straight at you. This lets you miraculously evade the bulk of the bullets. *7 seconds left.*
3. **Move to the right** again to dodge everything again. *3 seconds left.*
4. **Go down a bit** or you'll be killed by a bullet that travels along the top border of the screen, and just dodge the remainder of the bullets.

Comment: Your countdown gives this answer a sense of excitement! ;)